# Should I allow my users to update their registered email in SAAS application

Tags: saas

If my application is SAAS application and my users are doing communication from registered email to their clients (like sending invoices).
In this case should I allow my users to update their emails?

If yes then what would be impact on user's previous communications.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption of you have SaaS Application,if you are using registered email id as the username for the users to get authenticated in the system, then while updating the new emailid make sure that there is no other account exists with the new email address.

From my POV, there wont be any problem as long as you have a Logging facility which tracks all the email gone out for a particular customer.

Generally, SaaS application will not force the customers to stick with one particular email address throughout the lifetime of the user in the application.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. 
I had little doubt that can customer misuse this email update functionality to use free trial by updating their email to new fake email and create again new account with same old email to get infinite free trial?

Comment: This could possibly happen, there is no fool proof way to avoid duplicate accounts with different email address of a same member. However, i believe you might offer free/trial account valid for certain period, post this period they must upgrade to a paid version of your software.